# e-commerce website decision - Joomla with K2 Store or VirtueMart or Prestashop

Tags: joomla, paypal, prestashop, virtuemart

We have an existing webstore based on old Joomla 1.5 and VirtueMart. Store is outdated and has to be upgraded. We have an option to use Joomla 3 with K2 Store template, which looks like an easire option, because we already have a theme for it from the old webstore.
Since this is webstore, we also considered using Prestashop, but that would take longer to complete because of appearance customization.
These are our requirements:

- we need multi-language support (different articles for different countries)
- credit card and paypal support
- usage of coupon discount
- good future support
- collecting credit or bonus points and using in them in future orders

Is it better to continue with Joomla and K2 store or better to switch to Prestashop with some extra work?

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

We use Hikashop for Joomla, it will handle all your requested features and more.  They have free and paid versions available and it's fairly minimalistic to configure.

I find K2 bulky and cumbersome, and last I checked VirtueMart was not available for Joomla 3.

http://www.hikashop.com